# Mongo Java Driver -prematurely reached end of stream exception?

Tags: java, mongodb

We are using Mongo Java driver 3.3.0 to connect to Mongo DB.

We are getting an issue "org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Prematurely reached end of stream; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream"

We came to know that are 2 properties **connectTimeoutMS** and **socketTimeoutMS** whch can be used to change the timeout when providing them using mongodb connection string. We tried increasing their values but, we still see the issue.

We want to know if Mongo Java driver 3.3.0 supports **connectTimeoutMS** and **socketTimeoutMS** (OR) Is there a different solution to this problem.

Also, it seems there is another property to be used for configuring connection pools, **maxIdleTimeMS**. We do not use any connection pool, we use the default ones. Is this something which needs to fine tuned appropriately.

If someone has faced a similar issue, can you please provide your thoughts on this.

Comment: Whilst `connectTimeoutMS` and `keepAlive` are options you should be using as good practice, the most predominant cause of this is due to a long running cursor. For which actually points to a bigger problem of "why does the cursor stream need to be open for such a period of time"? In brief you're doing something that can likely be done better where that is the case. So you should be rather looking at what particular process(es) are in operation at the time when this error rises. Setting other options may buy you some time, but generally are only masking a deeper problem.